# Java : calling method in other class, Logical issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This is my case :

I have one class :

Calss :

Gui.java - includes the GUI

```
save(){//here we change the GUI which is called in the Gui.java, depends on the arraylist, after that we refresh the GUI
```

}

and a class popup.java

```
okbtn(){//here we add sth in the arraylist and call the methode save in the class GUI}
```

If I open the popupbox and click the button OK ,the okbtn() is called.
But how is it possible to change the UI of the specific GUI.java.

Gui.java : 
-Holds the UI like :private panel = new panel
-save() // refreshs the UI like for (String str : arraylist){ this.panel.addcontent(str))

Popupbox.java :
Gui ui = new Gui();

Adds sth. to an arraylist and calls the methode ui.save();

<--if I do ui.save() it wont change the UI which I see it changes the UI of the new class.

Do I have to add a public static to all of the GUI elements?
or what is the best way

Comment: couldn't get the logic issue in here.. `how is it possible to change the GUI of the specific GUI.java`. Could you try to rephrase your problem statement?

Comment: I was "logically" blown. Can you provide code in more detail. Seeing code may help a lot more then reading what it does.

Comment: Please, what do you expect, here on SO, from question of this nature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Do I have to add a public static? to all of the GUI elements?:*

No. Get that dirty thought out of your mind.

Instead, I would code to supply a business `interface` that `GUI` implements. And you can pass the instance of `GUI` to the `Popup` Just implement the method of the interface, then you pass the instance of the interface, which would be GUI, to the Popup class. Something like

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    public void save();
}

public class GUI implements SomeInterface {
    Popup popup = new Popup(this);

    @Override
    public void save() {
        // save
    }
}

public class Popup ...{
    private SomeInterface someInf;

    public Popup(SomeInterface someInf) {
        this.someInf = someInf;
    }
    ...
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        someInf.save();
    }
}
```